# Getting error when trying to add python file in our current file

Tags: python, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWFWI.jpg)I have created a folder in pycharm and create a file inside it. want to import this in my current file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5c0e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that `add` is not defined, cause it's not a keyword of Python, nor a function you're importing (like `from this_module import add`).

If you want to sum two elements, you will need the built-in function `sum` (it requires an iterable, like a list), so your code will become

```
a=2
b=3
c=sum([a,b])
print(c)  # 5
```

EDIT: After the second screenshot, you need to call 
`from airthmetic.airthmetic import add`

Btw it's *arithmetic*

Comment: "from airthmetic.airthmetic import add" its working. Thanks